# height doesn't go to 100%

Tags: html, css, height

I have two sections, results on the left and main on the right which reside in html > wrapper > container.

Now, the heights of both of these are not fixes and would want them to stretch to 100% depending on their contents. On some occasions, results are longer than main and vice versa. I've used 100% height, but it just doesn't seem to work. Please help!

```
html, body {
margin: 0;
padding: 0;
height: 100%;
}

#wrapper {
min-height: 100%;
position: relative;
width: 100%;
}

#container {
width: 1007px;
padding: 130px 0 0 0;
display: block;
}

.results {
width: 383px;
float: left;
background: 
#fff;
display: block;
-webkit-box-shadow: -2px 0px 8px -6px #000;
-moz-box-shadow: -2px 0px 8px -6px #000;
box-shadow: -2px 0px 8px -6px #000;
padding-bottom: 60px;
}

.main {
width: 606px;
float: left;
padding: 15px 0 0 16px;
position: relative;
background: url(images/pattern.png) repeat;
height: 100%;
bottom: 0px;
}

<html lang="en>
  <head></head>
  <body>
     <div id="wrapper">
        <div id="container" class="clear fix">
            <section class="results">
            </section>
            <section class="main">
            </section>
        </div>
     </div>
  </body>
  </html>
```

Comment: So you want the two columns to be the same size?  If so, try adding `overflow: auto` to the `#Wrapper`

Answer (score 0):

Try to use "absolute" in instead of "relative" in position attribute.
I did here and worked.

For example:

```
.main {
width: 606px;
float: left;
padding: 15px 0 0 16px;
position: absolute;
background: url(images/pattern.png) repeat;
height: 100%;
bottom: 0px;
}
```

Hugs,
Vinicius.

Comment: Hi Vinicus, thanks, but if I do that, the main section lies on top of the results section :(

Comment: To be honest, I don't know if exists a way to "force" a height property in this way. Why you can do 100% of div? Try do review your page design to fit the elements better, problably. So, good luck. hugs =)

Answer (score 0):

In many cases the problem arises when one states the height should be 100% but you need to ask the question, "100% of what?". That answer is the parent of that element so the next question is, "What is the parent's height set to?". If you don't have a height set to the parent, then 100% of nothing is nothing.